# Can I store value in a variable, the value which is outside the php tags

Tags: php, function, variables, tags

Can I to store value like:

```
<?php $var = ( ?>
<div>hello world</div>
<?php ) ?>
```

On above example I want to store "hello world" to $var

I know we can do this like:

```
<?php
$var = "<div>hello world</div>";
?>
```

But I don't want to do like this. Can I do with first method.

**Or you Can you suggest me if we can do something like this also:**

```
<?php function content(){ return (?>
<div>hello world</div>
<?php )}?>
```

Comment: _"But I don't want to do like this"_ - If I may ask, why don't you want to do it like that? Since you've added some restriction, giving us some background for them helps us to come up with possible alternative solutions, like using [output buffering](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php), reading from another file or similar.

Comment: No, you cannot. The reason is that between <?php ... ?> you need to provide correct PHP syntax. The statement `$var = (` is not a complete nor correct statement in PHP. It will generate an error. I cannot find any workaround for this...

Comment: You could use heredoc `<<<HTML`

Comment: @Daan - That's still within PHP tags though.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I know, just opening eyes for alternatives which OP maybe didn't know.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can use [heredoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax to store string constant into variable

Answer (score 0):

Whatever it is you are trying to do, there is probably a better option. But yes you can store generated output in a variable.

```
<?php
ob_start();
?>
Some content outside of php
<?php
$content = ob_get_clean();
// Now you can echo $content; or whatever you want to do with it
```